# Including the expiration date/time in AWS Cognito verficication email

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I've found out that when creating an account through my site using AWS Cognito, the verifcation code is valid for 24 hours. I'm using the AWS CDK to deploy my stacks to my AWS environment. In my main **cdk.ts** file, I have the following variables:

```js
const datetime: Date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
export const date: string = datetime.toLocaleDateString();
export const time: string = datetime.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
```

In my Cognito stack file, I have an HTML template for the email that the user receives when they signup which includes how long the code is valid for. Now I have been able to reference them successfully in this HTML template however, the date and time are incorrect as they are + 24 hours from when I deployed the stack as opposed to + 24 hours from when the email is sent out. How would I go about making it so that it's 24 hours from the email creation date?

Answer (score 0):

You can tap into the events that Cognito [triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html) and use a lambda to generate the email body.

Here's an example of a CDK setup for the user pool:

```
const userPool = new UserPool(this, 'UserPool', {
  selfSignUpEnabled: true, // Allow users to sign up
  autoVerify: { email: true }, // Verify email addresses by sending a verification code
  signInAliases: { email: true }, // Set email as an alias
  lambdaTriggers: {
    customMessage: cognitoMailTransformerLambda, // For custom emails
    postConfirmation: cognitoEventDispatcherLambda // Can be used for post confirm events such as setting up a database etc
  },
  customAttributes: {
    ...
  }
})
```